# Calculating Euclidean distance matrix of 2 image datasets via broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to learn broadcasting, so as an exercise, I'm trying to understand how to calculate a Euclidean distance matrix of two image datasets with only 1 loop.

This is the naive implementation that has been verified to work

```py
for i in range(num_train):
    for j in range(num_test):
        dists[i][j] = float(np.sum((np.array(x_train[i]) - np.array(x_test[j]))**2))**0.5
```

The below is my approach to transforming the naive implementation to a method that only requires one loop. This code does not work.

```py
for i in range(num_train):
    dists[i] = float(np.sum((np.array(x_test) - np.array(x_train[i]))**2))**0.5
```

I thought the `x_train[i]` would broadcast over the `x_test` matrix and create effectively the same operation, but it seems to be wrong when I manually review the results.

For reproducibility, we can define `x_train = numpy.random.random((5, 3, 10, 10))` and `x_test = numpy.random.random((5, 3, 10, 10))`

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I ran it against sample matrices and the output wasn't the same (original comment was asking how I verified my trial method does not work)

Comment: "_it doesn't work._" -- please [show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) how it doesn't work. There's no example data there for an SO contributor to try out and iterate on. Help us to help you -- supply example data.

Comment: I think it might help if you explained what shape you expect the output array `dists` to be.  Also, do the inputs NEED to be of the same size?

Answer (score 0):

You apparently invited us to do this:

```
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.random((5, 3, 10, 10))
x_test  = np.random.random((5, 3, 10, 10))

num_train = num_test = 5
dists = np.zeros((num_train, num_test))

for i in range(num_train):
    for j in range(num_test):
        dists[i][j] = float(np.sum((np.array(x_train[i]) - np.array(x_test[j]))**2))**0.5

print("Good so far!", dists.shape)

for i in range(num_train):
    dists[i] = float(np.sum((np.array(x_test) - np.array(x_train[i]))**2))**0.5
```

I just don't begin to see how that could work. Surely we want this instead?

```
for i in range(num_train):
    dists[i] = float(np.sum((np.array(x_test[i]) - np.array(x_train[i]))**2))**0.5
```

Subscripting by `[i]` changes the meaning of the expression.
Chalk it up to a typo?

---

The matrix shapes are nicely constant,
but using "random" values is the opposite of "reproducible".
Let's use boring constant values.

```
x_train = np.zeros((5, 3, 10, 10)) + .2
x_test  = np.zeros((5, 3, 10, 10)) + .3
```

Now both computation styles will yield values of `1.732`.

Rename to `dists2`, so we have `dists2[i] = float(...`.
Then, interrogating `(dists == dists2).all()` produces `True`, FTW.

Comment: I'm not sure if my English is the issue, but I don't think this is correct. I think my original question may have been misworded. The 2 loop implementation is the naive approach to show what output I want. I gave my non-working approach using 1 loop. The approach you suggest seems to give a different output to the 2-loop approach

Comment: I am willing to believe that. It would be helpful to understand the meanings of five, three, ten, and ten in your example, as the motivating use case behind this code is not yet clear. If constant .2 & .3 values aren't suitable, feel free to use `np.arange(...)` to flesh out the example.

Comment: In the example, we can interpret it as 5 images of 3 channels and 10x10 pixels, although this should work with any dimension of matrices (n x a x b x ... x i)