# Euclidean distance matrix of 2 n-d matricies without looping

Tags: python, numpy

I was told it is possible to calculate the euclidean distance matrix of 2 datasets of matrices (`matrix1.shape = (n_1, ...)` and `matrix2.shape = (n_2, ...)`, where we want to calculate the `n_1 * n_2` euclidean distance matrix) without using loops. I vaguely figure it's related to [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), but I'm not sure where to even start.

Is this possible? Most of the solutions online seem to require loops.

Comment: Are you trying to do the same thing as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75575779/calculating-euclidean-distance-matrix-of-2-image-datasets-via-broadcasting?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't think so. I'm quite new to coding from a math background, but it seems like that question is ok with 1 loop whereas I am trying to do it with no loops

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(2,3,4)
b = np.random.rand(5,3,4)

n = np.linalg.norm(a[:,None]-b, axis=(2,3))
```

The `None` creates a new axis for broadcasting, `axis=(2,3)` tells on which axes to compute the norm from.

Comment: Yes, but how does `np.norm()` do it without looping?

Comment: What do you mean? It loops internally but in highly optimized c++ code. When people say "without looping" it usually means without any 'slow native python loops'. There is no way it could be done without _any_ sort of loop at _any_ level.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I got confused for a minute. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this to not only be restricted to just a 3 dim matrix?

Comment: Sure, you just need to extend the `axis` argument accordingly, either manually or programmatically e.g. `axis=tuple(range(2, len(a.shape)+1))`